# Angular multiple views render with stateProvider - ui.router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mind bugging problem. I`m new to Angular and I want to obtain the following behavior:

I have a defaultView in app.js:

```
$stateProvider
        .state("defaultView", {
             url: '/home',
             controller: "MatrixController",
             templateUrl: "assets/js/angular/templates/matrix.html"
        })
        .state("defaultView.createDiet", {
             url: '/create-diet',
             controller: "ModalController",
             templateUrl: "assets/js/angular/templates/createDietModal.html"
        });
```

And in the default view, I have:

```
<div class="wrapperCalendar" ui-view>
       <div data-ui-view="defaultView"></div>
        <div data-ui-view="createDiet"></div>
</div>
```

Basically I am trying to achieve an opening of a dialog (bootstrap modal) that is brought from another route, but I don't want to change the main view (defaultview). I just want to get the HTML for the dialog, insert it in the page without losing another section, and open it. Do you have any idea how can I acomplish that ?

Comment: You wish to rely on routing to invoke the opening of a dialog???

Comment: Yes, I want that because I want to be able to give the link to another person and when he access it, the dialog will open instantly (it contains important information)

Comment: Alternative, pass your intent to open the dialog as a state param to the parent view (default view), and invoke the dialog from that view's constructor.